# How can I detect the pressing of any key on the keyboard in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

When the mouse pointer is in the Entry widget, I would like the pressing of any key of the keyboard (without using a loop) to trigger the print: `Pressure detected! You pressed any key`. What should I write in the function to achieve this? Can you show us a solution with demo code?

Currently in my code, clicking on the  Entry widget is detected, but I don't want to get this. I want to get a key press.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def detects_key_press(event):
    print("Pressure detected! You pressed any key")

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<1>", detects_key_press)
entry.pack(fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your `bind` command invokes your function whenever you press "Mouse button 1" (i.e., `"<1>"`). You'll need to change this to `"<Key>"`. To see what specific key was pressed, you can then access `event.char`. Make sure to navigate into the `Entry` field first with a mouse click.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def detects_key_press(event):
    print(f"Pressure detected! You pressed {event.char}")

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Key>", detects_key_press)
entry.pack(fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

**Demo**

[image: demo key pressed]

See [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.html) for a reference to all specific key bindings. E.g., you can specify `"<Key-a>"` if you only want the event to be invoked on pressing the key `a`.